# JavaScript configuration manager class

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to be able to instantiate a JavaScript object as follows:

```
var c = new MyConfig({
    'server': 'servername',
    'kfc': true,
    'code': true,
    'test': true
});
```

Something like that. I want the individual attributes to be available with something like:

```
c.getConfig('nfc'); which should return true / false etc.
```

I get confused on little stuff like should I use literal or constructor function.

Can someone assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a special constructor; an object is perfectly suited to that.

```
var c = {
    server: 'servername',
    kfc: true,
    code: true,
    test: true
};
```

And to access a property, it's as simple as `c.kfc`, or `c['kfc']` if you need to access the property dynamically.